# Join mysql result with redis

Tags: mysql, database, caching, redis

Suppose I have two tables
1. Inventory ( id, quantity, productId).
2. Products (id, name, price).
I have all the products cashed in redis and I want to fetch the inventory data from mysql and join them with the cached products data in redis using productId.

```
const inventoryData = Select * from inventory;

inventoryData.map(item => {
  id: item.id, 
  quantity: item.quantity
  product: getFromCache(item.productId)
}).
```

Is this a good approach..
Any alternatives, examples or resources.... 
thank you

Comment: To my knowledge this can't be done directly without a middleware script/language to connect the two, elaborate more on the context and what you want to do.

Comment: A good improvement  would be to go get all products in one trip to the cache, using https://redis.io/commands/mget, as it seems you are getting them one by one, wasting a lot in round trip time.

Comment: Don't use map. Do as @LeoMurillo suggests. Unless, you're using something like dataloader.